# How can I configure my nft project with the sugar cli to allowlist only my partner and I to mint 2 nfts before the public mint goes live?

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine-v2, sugar

Basically I just want 2 of 50 nfts to be allowlisted and the rest would just be publicly mintable after the go live date?

Answer (score 1):

Considering it's only two NFTs. You can mint them from the command line with the [mint](https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/commands#mint) command from Sugar.

Comment: Be sure you don't have the gatekeeper on.

Answer (score 0):

As HNBL mentioned you can just use the Sugar CLI. Sugar allows the Auth wallet to bypass certain restrictions so that it can always mint.

Command should be `sugar mint`

If you want to see additional options you can run `sugar mint -h` to see a full list of params you can pass it.